# Questions about running redis as an ECS service + service discovery

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, service-discovery

I'm trying to understand how service discovery / cloudmap works with ECS. I have a toy repo (link below) with a simple flask app that gets and sets the `foo` key from redis. It works as expected locally in docker-compose, and I am working on a terraform configuration (in the same repo) to make this work in ECS so that the flask task can communicate to the redis task.

I think I'm close to making this work, but I'm getting the following error in flask for routes that make calls to redis:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to default-redis.default-sd-ns:6379. Name or service not known.
```

- `default-redis.default-sd-ns` is the name of the service discovery service and CloudMap private dns namespace. It is the value for the `REDIS_HOST` environment variable in my flask app.
- there is an `A` record in Route 53 for `default-redis.default-sd-ns` that points to the private IP of the redis task in ECS
- I'm using Fargate launch types for both the flask app and the redis service. The flask app is passing health checks and I can access it over it's the subdomain that I configured it to run on.

Here's a link to the git repo where I'm work on this toy project and terraform configuration: [flask-redis-ecs-terraform](https://github.com/briancaffey/flask-redis-ecs-terraform). Does anyone have an example project that shows how to configure a service like redis with CloudMap so that other tasks can communicate with it?

I was previously trying to do this with EC2 launch types, but I ran into ENI errors that prevented tasks from being placed. I have done a lot searches for examples, but I can't find anything that has been able to give me a complete example of this type of task <-> task communication.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I could debug the connectivity issue between my flask app and the redis service in ECS?

---

One a separate topic, I'm doing this to support containerized ad-hoc development environments that can be used to rapidly test new features. Instead of trying to use a shared, always on ElastiCache instance, or use ElastiCache instances per ad-hoc environment, I wanted to try to use a standalone redis service in ECS per environment. This small change has resulted in a lot of changes to the terraform configuration, particularly with respect to networking settings. I was originally using `bridge` networking and didn't need to worry about communication between tasks. I probably won't be using any service discovery in other more permanent / stable environments since I can rely on ElastiCache for using redis. Does this make sense?

I'm currently working on configuring ECS Exec to see if I can query that Route 53 record from my app container.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this question up but forgot to publish. In the meantime I read this article (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html) that mentions that you need to enable DNS hostname. I then found in the AWS VPC module I'm using that there is a setting called [enable_dns_hostnames](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest#input_enable_dns_hostnames) which is `false` by default. Setting this to true fixed the issue and I'm now able to access redis from my flask container